# phpspec - method returns object instead of string

Tags: php, symfony, testing, phpspec

I'm still fresh in phpspec but usually I'm finding a solution when I struggle with something but this one is tough.

I've tried many different approaches and I haven't found a solution. I'm using Symfony2.

I have a class that I want to test:

```
class MyClass
{

    public function getDataForChildren(MyObject $object)
    {
        foreach ($object->getChildren() as $child) {
            $query = \json_decode($child->getJsonQuery(), true);
            $data = $this->someFetcher->getData($query);
            $child->setData($data);
        }
        return $object;
    }

}
```

And here's how look my spec class:

```
class MyClassSpec
{

    function let(SomeFetcher $someFetcher)
    {
        $this->beConstructedWith($someFetcher);
    }

    function it_is_initializable()
    {
        $this->shouldHaveType('MyClass');
    }

    function it_should_get_data_for_children_and_return_object(
        MyClass $object,
        MyClass $child, // it means that MyClass has a self-reference to MyClass
        $someFetcher
    )
    {
        $query = '{"id":1}';

        $returnCollection = new ArrayCollection(array($child));

        $object->getChildren()->shouldBeCalled()->willReturn($returnCollection);

        $child->getJsonQuery()->shouldBeCalled()->willReturn($query);

        $someFetcher->getData($query)->shouldBeCalled();

        $this->getDataForChildren($object);
    }

}
```

And after running phpspec I'm getting this error:

```
warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in
```

I have no idea how to solve this problem. If anyone has a clue, please help.

Comment: the warning is clear, `$child->getJsonQuery()` is an object, json_decode expects string, look in the class if there is a method like `$child->getJsonQuery()->jsonString()` or something like that

Comment: there is:
`$child->getJsonQuery()`
and it's stubbed:
`$child->getJsonQuery()->shouldBeCalled()->willReturn($query);`.

`$child` is an entity and jsonQuery is a field in it, so when the `$child->getJsonQuery()` is called I thought that it will return string (because I stubbed it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common stumbling block with PhpSpec, the declaration:

```
   MyClass $child
```

means that a Collaborator object of $child will be set up with the same interface of MyClass.
When child->getJsonQuery() is called in the SUT (class you're testing), it will return a *MethodProphecy* not the string you expect it to return.

What you want to say is that your ArrayCollection will contain *not* $child itself (which is a Collaborator object), but the real object that the collaborator is wrapped around. You do it like this:

```
$returnCollection = new ArrayCollection(array($child->getWrappedObject()));
```

> In addition, you should not be using (i.e. is is superfluous) both
>   shouldBeCalled() and willReturn() on the same Collaborator, one or the
>   other is sufficient. If you've specified what the collabrator  will
>   return, it is clear that it is going to be called witin the SUT.
>   shouldBeCalled() should be used in the "assert" part of the test in
>   order to confirm that the Collaborator was called with the expected
>   arguments, or at the right time.

Your final SUT and spec should look something like this:

```
   class MyClass
   {

        /**
         * @var SomeFetcher
         */
        private $someFetcher;

        public function getDataForChildren(MyObject $object)
        {
            foreach ($object->getChildren() as $child) {
                $query = \json_decode($child->getJsonQuery(), true);
                $data = $this->someFetcher->getData($query);
                $child->setData($data);
            }
            return $object;
        }

        public function getJsonQuery()
        {
        }

        public function setData()
        {
        }

        public function __construct(SomeFetcher $someFetcher)
        {
            $this->someFetcher = $someFetcher;
        }
    }
```

---

```
class MyClassSpec extends ObjectBehavior
{

    function let(SomeFetcher $someFetcher)
    {
        $this->beConstructedWith($someFetcher);
    }

    function it_should_get_data_for_children_and_return_object(
        MyObject $object,
        MyClass $child, // it means that MyClass has a self-reference to MyClass
        SomeFetcher $someFetcher
    )
    {
        $query = '{"id":1}';

        $returnCollection = new ArrayCollection(array($child->getWrappedObject()));

        $object->getChildren()->willReturn($returnCollection);

        $child->getJsonQuery()->willReturn($query);
        $child->setData(Argument::any())->shouldBeCalled();

        $someFetcher->getData(array('id' => 1))->shouldBeCalled();

        $this->getDataForChildren($object);
    }

}
```

Also, the line

```
$query = \json_decode($child->getJsonQuery(), true);
```

Will produce a associated array in $query, i.e. array('id' => 1) (this is what the second 'true' argument to json_encode stipulates), therefore you'd expect $someFetcher->getData() to be called with the latter, hence:

```
$someFetcher->getData(array('id' => 1))->shouldBeCalled();
```